# ¿"Se podía ver venir", "se podría haber visto venir" o "lo podría haber visto venir"?

Tags: gramática, conjugación, significado-en-contexto

Escuché a alguien diciendo que lo esperable era que se hubieran anticipado a algo malo que sucedió, pero como no hubo plan de contingencia las consecuencias están a la vista, específicamente dijo:

- Se **podría ver venir**(=..could see that coming..)

Pensé que era un error porque incluso los que escucharon se dieron cuenta que algo estaba mal con la frase, pero se entendió.

Pensé que debería haber dicho:

- Se **podría haber visto venir**"(=..could've seen that..)

, pero ahora pienso que también funciona:

- **Podrían**/**Deberían haberlo visto venir**(Porque "se" se refiere a "los encargados de verlo venir")

¿"Se podría ver venir" es correcto gramaticalmente?

¿"Se podría ver venir" es correcto en el caso de que eso malo que ocurrió ocurrierra cíclicamente y cada vez que esto pasara se generarían anticuerpos para contrarrestarlo o incluso en ese caso debería haber dicho:

- Ojalá **pudieran verlo venir**(=>Lo esperable/pertinente es que lo vean venir/Lo esperable es que lo hagan)

o

- Ojalá **puedan verlo venir**(=>En el caso de que el suceso todavía no ocurre)

---

EDIT: Sí, me falto el "it", "that" o "sth", editado, pero el evento venía en el ej. antes, pero quise mostrar su equivalencia literal en inglés para simplificarlo y **mi pregunta es sólo en español y sobre que tiempo verbal se debe usar**.

Voy a seleccionar un solo ejemplo para no enredar, en un partido de fútbol:

- A: Al jugador 6 lo repruebo.
- B: Reprobado para mi como lateral izquierdo.
- C: Pero lo expone el DT, lo hace jugar en un lugar que no acostumbra y por eso marcó mal al puntero izquierdo (11), teniendo incluso disponible al jugador 6b.
- D: El jugador 6 ya había tenido un mal partido enfrentando al jugador de otro equipo (11b), ahora le tocaba contra el jugador 11, era.., **se podía ver venir** lo que iba a pasar(¿el DT lo podría haber visto venir?).

¿Es correcto "**se podía ver venir** lo que iba a pasar" en este ejemplo? o es mejor decir "**se podría haber visto venir** esto o "**lo podría haber visto venir**"?" (El DT podría haberse dado cuenta que era mejor que no jugara el jugador 6 porque ya había jugado mal, como no lo hizo el resultado final fue adverso)

Gracias.

EDIT2:

> Ese <s>"lo esperaba"</s>, sería mejor convertirlo en "esperable".... lo esperable era que se hubiera anticipado....

En ningún lado dice "lo esperaba", dice claramente "lo **esperable**", lo puedes ver en mi pregunta y en en quote de otra respuesta. No tergiversar. Gracias.

> La frase hubiera terminado correctamente diciendo a) "Lo podría haber previsto" ó b) "Se podría haber evitado. Pero nunca en este contexto, "Se <s>podría</s> ver venir".

No es "se podría ver venir", es "se **podía** ver venir" en el ejemplo (2) del partido. Es una sutileza, pero quiero aclararlo.

Comment: to see something coming is an idiomatic expression in English, not in Spanish. But there is also the literal meaning: I could see the storm coming. Veia la tormenta que venía/llegaba. Se podría ver venir la tormenta. The storm could be seen coming.

Comment: Se podría ver venir [algo]. X could be seen coming. You should fix your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "ver venir" is correct and usual in Spanish. The only difference with English is that in Spanish we use the infinitive "venir" while in English we use the present participle "coming". Syntactically, the verb "ver" is a verb of perception and, as such, it can take an infinitival object complement:

- Vi el avión despegar. (I saw the plane take off.)
- Veo a mis hijos crecer. (I see my children grow up.)

I think that what the person meant to say by:

- Se podría ver venir.

was:

- Se podía ver venir. (You could -- in the past -- see it coming.)

With the conditional "podría", the phrase is grammatical but some special context would be required for it to work, for example:

-- Yo creo que una tormenta así se tiene que poder ver venir. (I think it should be possible to see a storm like this coming.)

-- Se podría ver venir si se tuvieran los instrumentos adecuados. (I use the passive though in English impersonal "you" with the active would be more usual: It could -- conditional -- be seen coming if the appropriate instruments were available.)

In answer to the question in the comment including an example related to football/soccer:

"El jugador ya había tenido un mal partido enfrentando al jugador de otro equipo, ahora le tocaba éste, que era más difícil. **Se podía ver venir** lo que iba a pasar."

The example above can be translated as follows:

- It was possible (given the circumstances) to guess what was going to happen.

It is not clear if the sentence implies criticism, but it may (it was possible to guess, but nobody did). However, it might be the case that the coach saw it coming and made some tactical change.

Instead, if we say:

"Se **podría haber visto** venir lo que iba a pasar."

the criticism is more explicit, the implication being that nobody saw it coming although the evidence was there. This is a counterfactual sentence.

Comment: Se podiá ver venir. Cannot be see *it* coming. There is a special meaning to: to see it coming. Which is not the literal meaning of see something coming. And really, in Spanish, wouldn't you actually say: Se podrái ver venir esta situación o [algo]?

Comment: My understanding is that in "see it coming" the pronoun "it" refers to some situation. I agree with you that there "see" does not indicate physical but mental perception and that the meaning is figurative, but I think that, grammatically speaking, the construction is parallel to "I saw the bus coming". In Spanish, we use the feminine pronoun "la" with exactly the same figurative meaning, with "la" referring to the situation: *(Me) la vi venir*.

Comment: Yes: See X coming. I think the OP's Se podría ver venir, given as "could see coming" is just a bad question as regards the Spanish and the English. Se podría ver venir la tormenta. Se la podría ver venir.

Comment: @Gustavson thank you, how do you decide what tense to use in Spanish? Football example: "El jugador ya había tenido un mal partido enfrentando al jugador de otro equipo, ahora le tocaba éste, que es más difícil, era.., se podía ver venir lo que iba a pasar". Or perhaps you should say either: "se podría haber visto venir" or "lo podría haber visto"(si el DT lo hubiera visto venir, no tendrían un resultado adverso)

Comment: You may find the answer to your question as an addition to my original reply.

Answer (score 1):

La primera opción es correcta en ambos ejemplos.

> [..] Lo esperable era que se hubieran anticipado a algo malo que sucedió,
> pero como no hubo plan de contingencia las consecuencias están a la
> vista, específicamente dijo:
>
> Se podría ver venir

El significado es equivalente a "se podría prever", "podrían verlo venir" o "podría verse venir". El tiempo verbal indica, si no está claro ya con la primera alternativa que propongo "se podría prever", que quien habla propone que existe la posibilidad de anticiparse. "Se podría mejorar', "se podría evitar", "se podría ver venir". Es esta última, **sin embargo**, una opción que a mí tampoco me suena natural. Quizás porque se trate de una frase en un tono formal ("se podría" + infinitivo) utilizando una expresión, *ver venir*, que no lo es. O quizás porque *poder ver venir* son ya tres verbos y necesariamente tiene que generar alguna dificultad, a menos que sea una expresión habitual, que no lo es.

> D: El jugador 6 ya había tenido un mal partido enfrentando al jugador
> de otro equipo (11b), ahora le tocaba contra el jugador 11, era.., se
> podía ver venir lo que iba a pasar(¿el DT lo podría haber visto
> venir?).

**Se podía ver venir**: En aquel momento, durante el partido, se podía adivinar lo que iba a pasar. Podría haberse utilizado: "en aquel momento se veía venir lo que iba a pasar", que es la forma habitual. Añadir "podía" le da un tono más formal o literario, de la misma forma que ocurre entre "se adivinaba" y "se podía adivinar". También habría sido equivalente utilizar "podía verse venir", que es menos formal pero igualmente literario.

**Se podría haber visto venir**: En aquel momento, durante el partido, no se dieron cuenta de lo que iba a pasar, pero si hubieran estado más atentos o si hubieran hecho un mejor análisis de la situación, **podrían haber percibido** que eso iba a suceder (y haber intentado evitarlo).

**Lo podría haber visto venir**: Mismo cas que el anterior pero particularizando en una persona, señalándola (él o yo: "él lo podría haber visto venir" o "yo lo podría haber..."). El locutor se refiere claramente a "él", el *DT*.

El tono crítico se puede conseguir de las tres formas:

- "Se podía ver venir que iba a ocurrir pero no se hizo nada"
- "Se podría haber visto venir si se hubiera prestado atención o con un mejor conocimiento de los jugadores"
- "Lo podría haber visto venir si hubiera estado atento o si conociera mejor a su jugador"

La tercera opción es una crítica frontal o directa hacia un sujeto concreto. Las dos anteriores son más formales o elegantes, válidas tanto para referirse a en general, como a un grupo de personas concreto, como también hacia una persona concreta.

Comment: Excelente argumentación, porque de hecho en una intervención anterior A le dice a D algo como "esa es una forma de decirlo elegantemente y de no involucrar a alguien específico y para no involucrarse"(el mismo).

Answer (score 0):

Dado que la cuestión se desarrolla en este contexto " lo esperaba era que se hubiera anticipado a algo malo que sucedió, pero como no hubo plan de contingencia las consecuencias están a la vista...Se podría ver venir".

1. - Ese "lo esperaba", sería mejor convertirlo en "esperable".... lo esperable era que se hubiera anticipado....
2. - La "anticipación" nos muestra cual va a ser el recorrido de la frase y la incorrecta voz gramatical que se utiliza para termina y solucionar la expresión. "Se podría ver venir".
3. - La anticipación, nos indica que algo puede estar previsto ó ser evitado. Así utilizamos el prefijo "pre" que nos indica anterioridad, con lo que podemos optar en nuestro discurso dialéctico entre dos soluciones a un imprevisto / que se pudo evitar.
4. - La frase hubiera terminado correctamente diciendo a) "Lo podría haber previsto" ó b) "Se podría haber evitado. Pero nunca en este contexto, "Se podría ver venir".
5. - Cuando el acontecimiento no lo hubiera podido prever o ó no lo podría haber evitado. Simplemente es que "no lo vio venir".

Diego

Comment: En ningún lado dice "lo esperaba", no sé de donde sacaste eso, dice claramente "lo esperable", lo puedes ver en mi pregunta y en en quote de otra respuesta. El problema de estas frases es la repetición de 3 verbos, y de que suena mal la reiteración de "ver venir" y de aceptar o no los hechos tal cual son sin adjudicarle la responsabilidad a otro evento o a otras personas, o, de plano, cargarle la responsabilidad a alguien pero sutilmente al decirlo de esta forma. Unos dirán que es "elegancia", "siutiquería", otros que es "no quedar mal con nadie".

Comment: El problema de con "no lo vio venir", "lo podría haber previsto" es que le carga la responsabilidad al DT exclusivamente cuando podría recaer en él, en los dirigentes, en la institución, en su incapacidad histórica, o simplemente en que el jugador 11 era mucho mejor que cualquier otro 11a, 11b, 11c que haya enfrentado, o que incluso ningún 6a, 6b, 6c lo hubiera hecho mejor que el mismo 6, por lo tanto es un hecho indiscutible desde su perspectiva(see it coming). PD: No es "se podría ver venir", es "se podía ver venir" en el ejemplo (2) del partido. Es una sutileza, pero quiero aclararlo.